# Any way to access action variables from an admin generated partial in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I've got a partial that I'm using in a Symfony 1.4 admin generated module but I have some logic that I would prefer to keep in my action.  Is there anyway to access action vars in the partial?  In a regular template (ie: non admin generated), I could simply declare my var in my action as `$this->myVar` and then access it from within my template as `$myVar`, but is there any way to do this in an admin partial?

I've tried declaring it in my `preExecute()` method but the var is undefined in my partial template.

Am I doing something wrong, or is my only choice to use a component instead of a partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials and components don't have automatic access to action variables. They only see variables which are explicitly passed to them. In an admin generator module they usually get some useful parameters (e.g. the current object, helper object, configuration, form) but it depends on the current place of invocation (you can see the generated templates in the `cache` directory to find out which parameters they get). Partials also have access some global objects (e.g. request, user, response,...) which are available in every template file. You can use e.g. request attributes or slots:

```
// in an action
$this->getResponse()->setSlot('my_slot', $myVariable);

// in a partial
<?php include_slot('my_slot'); ?>
// or
<?php $my_variable = get_slot('my_slot'); ?>
```

But I think using a **component** is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you call this partial try to put the variable as a second parameter (or array of parameters) in the include_partial().

Comment: It's the admin generator that is creating the template that has include_partial().  All my access is via the generator.yml configuration file.  How can I do this through the yml file?